# Wordpress authentication for android application

Tags: php, android, wordpress, api, authentication

I Have a Wordpress website , i am writing an application for android . 
i want to register and login users from app , how can i do that using tokens ?
any suggestions will be usefull , 
any examples will be usefull   .

I searched alot , but not found anything usefull ... 
I have a Scenario for myself  : 
1- Create a table in wordpress and store tokens in that , and when user logined i give him a token and everytime he/she want to access something must send token , and in the backend api checks the token and ... 
What is yout opinion ?

Comment: you need to worry more about the security of a wordpress website than anything else. storing tokens isnt a great idea, is someone hacks the DB, they now have all your tokens. you need to uses sessions (if using PHP). research php security. however, i would reccomend not to use wordpress... if anything, develop a website in PHP/HTML/CSS/JS. wordpress has way too many moving parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching a lot I understand that , only with using WORDPRESS REST API , 
it is very easy to do what i want !

Please Please Go To The Wordpress Rest Api , And See The POWER OF IT !
Just By Adding Custom Plugins , You Can Do What You Want .